# paragraphe is not centring it self with images

Tags: html, css

The paragraph is not centering with images. The width is 80% of the article class but it begins from the start of the article class.
The images are centering very well by the parent class articles property Display lex and justiy-content center.
Can you help me with this?
Thanks.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: poppins;
}

.articles {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.article {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: wheat;
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  border: black 2px solid;
}

.article img {
  width: 80%;
}

.article p {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="articles">
    <div class="article">
      <img src="/imgs/article (1).jpg" alt="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae assumenda omnis officiis numquam illo explicabo.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="article">
      <img src="/imgs/article (2).jpg" alt="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae assumenda omnis officiis numquam illo explicabo.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="article">
      <img src="/imgs/article (3).jpg" alt="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae assumenda omnis officiis numquam illo explicabo.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="articles">
    <div class="article">
      <img src="/imgs/article (4).jpg" alt="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae assumenda omnis officiis numquam illo explicabo.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="article">
      <img src="/imgs/article (5).jpg" alt="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae assumenda omnis officiis numquam illo explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You do not need to 'justify-content: center;' when the display is 'block'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add margin in `.article p`
**CSS**

```css
.article p {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

In CSS change ***(.article)***:

```
.article {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: wheat;
  display: flex; /* instead block */
  flex-direction: column; /*added */
  align-items: center; /*added */
  text-align: center;
  border: black 2px solid;
}
```

[image]